# Jupyter becomes unresponsive when using backend osx

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, ipython, jupyter

Since I have updated IPython to Jupyter my notebooks become unresponsive (`*` next to input cell) when I specify `osx` as plotting backend. Commonly I do this by line magics `%pylab`, which automatically sets the backend to `osx`, or `%matplotlib osx`. Both commands make the notebook unresponsive. I made the following observations:

- The notebooks becomes unresponsive about 30 seconds after evaluation of one of the above magics.
- Even simple commands like `1+2` take about 7 seconds to produce output
- After an evaluation (and output) the notebook takes again roughly 7 seconds to return from its busy state
- Once unresponsive, the notebook does not become responsive again when changing the backend
- The backends `inline` and `notebook` work perfectly fine

I do not think that my problem has something to do with [Ipython issue #4431](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/4431) since it happens always ~30s after specifying the backend whether I type or not.

I use the following setup:

- Mac OS X El Captain 10.11.2
- Python 3.5.1
- Jupyter 1.0.0 (jupyter --version == 4.0.6)
- IPython 4.0.3

How do I get the `osx` backend working?

Comment: A well presented question. Do you know that this isn't a limitation of Jupyter on OSX (that is, have you seen it work as expected on another machine?). I don't Mac, so don't know.

Comment: I'm seeing a similar phenomenon with Jupyter qtconsole.  About 20 seconds after loading, every command takes between 5-10 seconds to execute.  OSX=10.11.3, Python 2.7.10, IPython 4.0.1, Jupyter 4.1.1.  However, it doesn't happen in a terminal version of ipython.